# question about filtering a dictionary using a list in python

Tags: python

with the following dictionary and array:

```
a = { 'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[1,2,3], 'c':[1,2,3,4,5] }
b = ['a','c']
```

I would like to filter a into a new dictionary to only have the key-values in the array b so i end up with:

```
c = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

So.. the obvious way to do this for me was the following:

```
(1) dict(map( lambda x:(x,a[x]), b))
```

Searching for different ways to do it I also see this:

```
(2) dict( (x, a[x]) for x in b)
```

I don't fully have my head around (2) but before I dive too deep into what is going on is there an advantage to using (2) over (1)? Or better yet is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Should be `for x in b` in (2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `map()` can always be substituted by a list comprehension.  The call

```
map(callable, iterable)
```

is equivalent to

```
[callable(x) for x in iterable]
```

If `callable` is a lambda-expression, the latter form is faster and more readable, which is why it is prefered in this case.

If you don't really need the list returned by `map()`, but only another "iterable", you can also replace the `map()` call by a generator expression

```
(callable(x) for x in iterable)
```

This won't create all items immediately.  The items are only created one by one while iterating over the generator.

In your example, the `dict` constructor only needs an iterable, which it will iterate over an insert all items straight into the new `dict` instance.  You don't need the intermediate list that a list comprehension or a call to `map()` would create.

Your option (2) is faster than (1), uses less memory, is more succinct and (in my opinion) more readable than (1).

Comment: so now i'm wondering what the point is of using map where the callable is a lambda expression.  Just learning python and (1) seems to be a common construct in tutorials.  Is there an example you would prefer (1) over (2)?

Comment: IIRC, list comprehensions were added in Python 2.0, so possibly your tutorial is for an older version of Python.

Answer (score 2):

Using python 2.7 and 3.0 syntax:

```
{ k:a[k] for k in b  }
```

Comment: okay for me that's not nearly as readable but maybe i could get used to it :)  I haven't graduated to python 2.7 yet..

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of **(2)** is that it uses a generator to produce the key-value tuples, so you avoid the overhead of the N method calls to `lambda x()` incurred by **(1)**.